# How to refresh python file every time I refresh my html page?

Tags: python

I want to re-run my python file every time i refresh my HTML page.
How can i do that?
HTML:

```html
    <div class="b">
        <div class="border">
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[0] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[1] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[2] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[3] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[4] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[5] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[6] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[7] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[8] }}</div>
            <div class="align">{{ str_product[9] }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Python:

```py
...
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def line():
    return render_template('line_chart.html', str_product=str_product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can solve your issue by doing this things:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def line():
    return render_template('line_chart.html', str_product=str_product)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What it does is, if you change anything in your python file then, it automatically detect that and as you said re-run python file(refresh). And if you change anything in HTML file also and save that. When you refresh webpage then you can see change in webpage. You can visit [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#debug-mode) for further more/detail information.